# Facing "the application was unable to start correctly 0xc00007b." after i compiled my code with g++ compiler on command prompt in Windows 10

Tags: c++, compilation, windows-10, command-prompt

I compiled a simple "Hello World" C++ code in command prompt (Windows 10), and then tried to run a.exe file, but got this well known error. Then I created a project in VS2019, and was able to run same code without any problem. Upon doing `ldd a.exe` all the dependent dlls were inside "/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32", so i copied executable over there, but still faced the same issue.

I also tried running in administrator mode, changing/troubleshooting the compatibility option to Windows 7/8 but none of them worked.

A couple of months back I was able to compile and run a code in this manner, but since then many software have been changed, so I kind off lost track which software change can cause this issue.

g++ -v ==>

```
 Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
 {Several configurations}...
 Thread model: win32
 gcc version 4.6.3
```

Is there some common solution which I can try?

Comment: It always amazes me how much time people spend trying to cram Linux/Unix originated software, like gcc, into an alien operating system that wasn't designed to run Linux/Unix-originated code. Even experienced developers will often have these kinds of difficulties, not to speak of people who are new to C++. Most of the time it will take much less time to simply install Linux from scratch, and get a fully working, fully configured, modern C++ compiler. It took me about hour and a half, last time. How much time have you already wasted here?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik INVESTED about 1 day over here,, and I think solving this kind of technical issue is what makes things fun. I tried every aspect and pages which i could from net, and still looking from my behalf if I can get its solution.